# How to fix "PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /var/www/.../vendor/laravel/RoutesRequests.php on line 156"

Tags: laravel, lumen

PHP Parse error:

> syntax error, unexpected '=' in
>   /var/www/.../api/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php
>   on line 156

I did a clean install of Lumen. I recently upgraded php to 7.3 but composer is still older.

Comment: In the future and for historical purposes show us the line.  It is using array destructuring: `[$method, $pathInfo] = $this->parseIncomingRequest($request);`

Comment: Yes sorry that was the line. Do you have any suggestions? I am currently still hitting that error and have updated php and composer to the latest stable versions

Comment: This is happening when you access your Lumen install on your server, not when you run a composer command, right?  The web server may have multiple versions installed and is still not using the correct PHP version.  In index.php, place `phpinfo();` somewhere and see whether the PHP version is 7.1+

Comment: That is correct. When I run that I see the php version is indeed 7.3.x.

Comment: That error doesn't make much sense then as 7.1+ supports array destructuring.  Could be a cache issue but unlikely.  If you copy `[$a, $b] = [1, 2]; echo $a, $b; die;` into index.php does this command print `12` to screen in browser?

Answer (score 1):

Update `PHP` to 7.3 OR downgrade `Lumen` to 7.9

Answer (score 0):

That error seems to be related to a PHP version issue. So I suggest you to check php version used in the site which fires the error.
Anyway you wish to update your local composer, try with this command in your terminal

```
composer self-update
```

Comment: So I've updated my composer to 1.9 and I'm still getting the same error. Any other suggestions? Do I need to restart my ubuntu server?

Comment: Sorry but I've answered related to update composer and not PHP. I'm still thinking that what fires that error is a matter of PHP versions. Can you verify if your cli version is the same that php files version? you should run php -v in console for cli version and `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` inside a file rendered from a browser.